# Destory a bootstrap 3.3.6 modal that's filled by djangos render_to_string

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

## Description

I have a page with multiple items and each of these have a information button. If this button is clicked a modal fades in and more inforamation should be displayed about the clicked item.

It's working like described, but only for the first clicked item. That means if you close the modal and click on another item you'll get always the inforamtion from the first clicked item. To prevent this I think I need to destroy somehow the modal, so bootstrap needs to create a new one.

## Problem

I have problems with destroying completely a modal with Bootstrap 3.3.6.
The problem is in "Info template/Modal content"

## Code

#### Item template (items.html)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% for item in items %}
    <a href="{% url 'info' item.id %}"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#modal"
        title="info item" data-tooltip>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info"></span>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

#### Info template/Modal content (info.html)

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Info</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>Info about "{{ item }}"...</p>
    <!-- PROBLEM PART: Should destory the modal... -->
    <script>
        $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function(){
            $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        });
    </script>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

#### views.py

```
def info_item(request, **kwargs):
    item = Items.objects.get(id=kwargs.get("item_id"))
    return HttpResponse(
        render_to_string(
            "info.html",
            {
                "item": item,
            }
        )
    )
```

Comment: Where are you adding multiple items? Is it in another view?

Comment: @AKS I updated the code (added the item loop)

Comment: I still don't see 1) which file is `info.html`, 2) how the `Info template/Modal content` file has been included in it.

Comment: @AKS The info.html is the `Info template/Modal content`. It's "included" by `render_to_string` in the `views.py`

Comment: You need to remove your `<script>` tag from `info.html` and add it to `items.html`. Please try that and let me know.

Comment: @AKS Nope, with the old and the new code (answer from @Uzbekjon) it's not working. That means information is only displayed for the first item and then it won't update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111225/discussion-between-aks-and-rwx).

Comment: @AKS If you are interested in my solution: I updated the question.

Comment: That's great. Please add your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

To solve my problem I do now `.load` the content in items.html by

```
<a href="{% url 'info' item.id %}"
    onclick="$('.modal-content').load('{% url 'info' item.id %}');"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#modal">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info"></span>
</a>
```

instead with only bootstraps integrated js.

```
<a href="{% url 'info' item.id %}"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#modal"
    title="info item" data-tooltip>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info"></span>
</a>
```

and I deleted the script part in info.html.

The problem was described in http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options

Answer (score 1):

`bs.modal` is not a class. `hidden.bs.modal` is custom event that is fired when a modal is closed. You probably want to empty the `.modal-content` contents.

```
    $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function(){
        $(this).parents('.modal-content').empty();
    });
```

Comment: Same behavior with this